# Worcloud2 returns blank image instead of desired output

Tags: r, function, plot, cran, word-cloud

I am currently trying to use the library wordcloud2 from R to do a project for my university.

I am following the instructions of [cran.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html)

I have managed to do the basic tasks

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(devtools)
wordcloud2(data = demoFreq)

wordcloud2(demoFreq, color = "random-light", backgroundColor = "grey")
```

however, if I try something more complex, like trying to add a logo

```
wordcloud2(demoFreq, figPath = "logo.png", size = 1.5,color = "skyblue")
```

the program returns the image without the word cloud on it (the logo is in the same folder as the R code)

```
letterCloud(demoFreq, word = "R", size = 2)
```

does not return anything at all.

I don't know what is wrong with my code, since I am copying the exact instructions of the webpage. Can someone please help me?

Comment: There is an open issue with the same symptoms: [mask and letterCloud silently fail #12](https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/12) A work around is refreshing the rstudio viewer, or opening in a browser.

Comment: @Isaiah Thanks. Unfortunately, I need to include the code in a R markdown file and when I knit it, the error manifests too and I cannot refresh there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, using wordcloud2 with flexdashboard. In that cas I solved installing version 0.2.2 of wordcloud2, from github, instead of 0.2.1 from CRAN: 'devtools::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")'.